# Replacing a jQuery script using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

A website is running a jQuery script. I want to use a Chrome Extension to have the site run my own version of the jQuery script, and not the normal one.

So far, I've managed to make the chrome extension find where the website calls the normal script, and I've replaced it with my own:

```
document.querySelector("script[src^='website.com/originaljqueryscript']").src = 'myjqueryscript';
```

As a test, I made myjqueryscript the exact same script as the originaljqueryscript. I set the run_at in the manifest to run at document_end.

When I try to open the website with my script enabled, the console logged an error `$(...).dialog is not a function`. I think this is because jQuery is not loaded in my chrome extension. So then I found which version of jQuery the website is using, and added that to my chrome extension. Now I get this error: `$(…).dialog is not a function` I believe that error is due to a conflict between the two jQuerys that have been loaded (one on the website, one from my extension).

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to replace a websites jQuery script with my own?

Comment: jQuery is defined as IIFE and so, it will be on action immediately after loaded.  Even if you remove the jQuery, the contents will be cached untill there is a browser refresh. If you refresh it, the same happen again.

Comment: I see, thanks. I suppose then my plan of "replacing" a jquery script on a live website is not quite possible, since the original script will always be loaded?

Comment: Yes. But if you want, you can block all jQuery CDN and add your own jQuery file

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a very specific website, loading jQuery from a specific URL, you can use [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to intercept the request to jQuery and redirect it to a file bundled in your extension. E.g.:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getUrl("js/myjquery.js")}; },
  {urls: ["https://example.com/js/jquery.js"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

(Note: this sample is very minimal; you may need to include and inspect request headers to make sure that the source page is your target site - you really don't want to replace a CDN-provided jQuery for all sites)

This assumes that the website does not use [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) checks, however I believe that it will bypass a `script-src` Content Security Policy (redirect is transparent).

---

Note that `.dialog()` is part of jQuery UI, not core jQuery; the site presumably loads both, and you'll need to intercept both. It's possible that the site actually bundles them together.

Comment: Would not an alternative be to have a MutationObserver loaded at `document_start` watching for matching `<script>` elements to be added. When found, immediately replace/alter such that what ends up in the DOM is a `<script>` pointing to your jQuery? This would get around the subresource Integrity checks issue. I'm not sure if you would also need to block (not redirect) the request for the original script (I'd have to see what actually gets transmitted; presumably blocking is not needed if the change occurs in the MutationObserver, but I'd test to be sure).

Comment: A MutationObserver will probably be late with the event.. But combined with blocking it will likely work. Anyway, subresource integrity isn't a very common scenario - but I did include a disclaimer that it will break this intercept.